# android - Retrieve images from firebase with two apps

Tags: android, firebase, picasso, firebase-storage

I am new to app development. I have two apps linked in firebase, one for sending image to Firebase Storage and image url to Firebase Realtime Database and one for retrieving all images with RecyclerView. The first app is running fine. But the second doesn't do anything. It only shows the layout arrivals.

**Code of arrivals.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="gr.packagename.name.MainActivity"
     android:background="@drawable/background">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/arrivals_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code of model.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/clothesimage"
        android:src="@drawable/men"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/categoryimage"
        android:text="category"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/clothesimage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Code of arrivals.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class arrivals extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference mdatabase;
RecyclerView rv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.arrivals);

    mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Images");

    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.arrivals_list);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Images, ImageViewHolder> firebaseadapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Images, ImageViewHolder>(
            Images.class,
            R.layout.list_content,
            ImageViewHolder.class,
            mdatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ImageViewHolder viewHolder, Images model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setCategory(model.getCategory());
            viewHolder.setImageurl(getApplicationContext(), model.getImageurl());

        }
    };

    rv.setAdapter(firebaseadapter);
}

public static class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setCategory(String category){

        TextView categoryimg = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.categoryimage);
        categoryimg.setText(category);

    }

    public void setImageurl(Context ctx, String imageurl){

        ImageView img = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.clothesimage);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(imageurl).into(img);
    }
}
}
```

**Code of Images.java**

```
public class Images {

private String imageurl;
private String category;

public Images() {
}


public String getImageurl() {
    return imageurl;
}

public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
    this.imageurl = imageurl;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}
}
```

Comment: Does the code return any errors in LogCat?

Comment: No I'm running app on a smartphone and it starts but it shows only the layout without the images in RecyclerView.

Comment: Can you post your LogCat data from when you open the layout?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/d62arq